# iDRAC6 Virtual Media native library cannot be loaded

Tags: linux, java, dell, drac

When attempting to mount Virtual Media on a iDRAC6 IP KVM session I get the following error:

[image: The Virtual Media program will close. Reason: The Virtual Media native library cannot be loaded.]

I'm using Ubuntu 9.04 and:

$ javaws -version
Java(TM) Web Start 1.6.0_16

$ uname -a
Linux aud22419-linux 2.6.28-15-generic #51-Ubuntu SMP Mon Aug 31 13:39:06 UTC 2009 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ firefox -version
Mozilla Firefox 3.0.14, Copyright (c) 1998 - 2009 mozilla.org

On Windows + IE it (unsurprisingly) works.

I've just gotten off the phone with the Dell tech support and I was told it is known to work on Linux + Firefox, albeit Ubuntu is not supported (by Dell, that is).

Has anyone out there managed to mount virtual media in the same scenario?

Answer (score 2):

use a 32 bit jre. sun jre 1.6.0 update 16 worked fine for me, as did the 32bit openjdk.

Simply tell firefox to open the jnlp with the 32-bit javaws you install. You may need to run javaws /path/to/your/saved/jnlp to see if there are any 32 bit libraries missing as well. In my case it bitched that it couldn't find libXtst so I just did a yum -y install libXtst.i586 on Fedora 11 and I was working; obviously wiht Ubuntu commands will be a little different, but I'm more or less confident similar steps will get you working...

Answer (score 1):

im seeing the same thing on an ibm server, and have seen posts for hp servers for the same; I have it working on a 32 bit linux system, but not on a 64-bit system. I rather suspect that a 32 bit library needs to be loaded. On Fedora (x86_64)/RHEL5(i386) here... i'll post back if I manage to figure out just what...

Answer (score 1):

On Fedora 12 x86-64, you can use the following workaround.  Remove the existing OpenJDK and install the i686 version:

```
 # yum remove java-1.6.0-openjdk-1:1.6.0.0-33.b16.fc12.x86_64
 # yum install java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0-31.b16.fc12.i686
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately for me using 32bit java didn't help. But I found this one in `iDRAC7_1.66.65_A00_ReleaseNotes.txt`:

```
* Issue 53:
  On servers with RHEL 5.x operating system, after upgrading to Java 1.7.0, 
  attempting to launch the Java Virtual Media, Virtual Console, or Boot Capture 
  plug-in results in an “Unable to load Native Library” message, and the Virtual 
  Media is disabled. 
  This issue is caused by the Security Enhanced Linux(SELINUX) “allow_execmod” 
  policy being set to “off”, preventing the Virtual Media operation.

  Resolution:
  set the 'allow_execmod'  policy to 'on' by running the following command:
  setsebool -P allow_execmod on

  Versions/Systems Affected
  All versions of iDRAC on 12th generation Dell PowerEdge Servers.
```

Thad didn't help me either, but maybe it will help somebody else.